# JQuery string to Object Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I call the function tabulator() with these params.

```
$("#tableObj").tabulator("addRow", {id:1, Name:"John", Age:"20"}, true);
```

I want to pass the Array elements name dynamically, 
read from a Json `( '{id:1, Name:"John", Age:"20"}' )`.

I mean that column names will change.
Ex : `{id:1, Company:"myComp", Address:"myaddress"}`

How can I create theses objs from Strings or JSon text?

Comment: loop over the array and reference the objects?

Comment: I am not aware of a jQuery function `tabulator()`. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: Yes, It belongs to Dynamic Html Table.

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(text)`

Comment: $("#tableObj").tabulator("addRow", {json.Company:json["Company"]}, true);
But do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `JSON.parse` but be aware that `id:1, Name:"John", Age:"20"` is NOT valid JSON. The keys must be wrapped in quotes, otherwise it will produce an error.

```
var str = '{"id":1, "Name":"John", "Age":"20"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);

$("#tableObj").tabulator("addRow", obj, true);
```